# Is there any way to show that an equation of this form splits?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

If I have this exact sequence $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, does it split? If so how do I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint: you could replace the sequence by $Z^2 \to B \to ker(Z^n \to Z) \to 0$

Comment: Why are you allowed to do that?

Comment: since $B$ maps onto the kernel of this map. Therefore you can restrict the image (as always you can write $f: X \to f(X)$) and this is always surjective; hence the $0$ at the end